# Сравнение экземпляров класса по указателям

Tags: указатели, c++

Есть некий класс `element{}`.
Я создаю несколько экземпляров этого класса и мне необходимо сравнить их.

```
element* firstElement;
element* secondElement;
while(isEquals(firstElement,secondElement)){
            amount++;
}
```

Как мне сделать функцию-член `isEquals(element*,element*)`?

Comment: @fasfsasf, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Сравнение объектов в отрыве от их семантики лишено смысла.

Возьмём, например, объект, представляющий человека, с полями `firstName` (имя) и `lastName` (фамилия). Два различных человека, даже если их и зовут одинаково, — это всё равно разные люди. Поэтому в этом случае сравнение не может опираться на значения полей, разные физически объекты не равны между собой. Здесь нужно сравнение указателей.

Возьмём теперь объект, представляющий собой условия, при которых проходит химическая реакция, с полями `temperature` (температура) и `pressure` (давление). Очевидно, что два набора условий совпадают тогда и только тогда, когда их поля совпадают. То есть нам не надо брать в расчёт указатели, а лишь значения полей.

Возьмём теперь объект, представляющий собой рациональное число, с полями `numerator` (числитель) и `denominator` (знаменатель). Числа не имеют самостоятельной сущности, поэтому два таких числа равны тогда и только тогда, когда равны их значения. То есть, для чисел `a` и `b` условие равенства

```
a.numerator * b.denominator == b.numerator * a.denominator
```

Вы видите, что условие равенства невозможно выдумать опираясь лишь на «голый» список полей объекта, семантика важна.

Answer (score 2):

во первых на хешкоде запрещена "работа за автора"

во вторых что сложного в создании такой функции? вам только и надо что внутри функции поочерёдно сравнивать каждое поле двух объектов, и если хоть одно не совпадает то вернуть false...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых в Вашем коде не создается объект, а лишь объявлены два указателя на класс.
Для того, чтобы сравнивать между собой два экземпляра класса, Вы должны "научить" класс делать такое сравнение. Для этого применяется Перегрузка Операторов (в Вашем случае оператора ==) .